# Rspec testing, calling controller method received NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So I was just trying to call a log_in method from user controller in the RSpec as

```
it "should get the index page" do
  @user = User.new({ :email => "employee@test.com" })
  log_in(@user)
  get 'index'
  response.should be_success
end
```

The result I got is like

```
1) EmployeesController GET 'index' should get the index page
   Failure/Error: log_in(user)
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `log_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x4ac0328>
   # ./spec/controllers/employees_controller_spec.rb:11:in `user_log_in'
   # ./spec/controllers/employees_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks

**Edited March 11th, 2011**

Here is the log_in method which is in UserController

```
  def log_in(user)
    session[:current_user] = user.id
  end
```

Comment: Any chance you are using Devise?

Comment: @raidfive No, I didn't use Devise

Comment: Is the method `user_log_in` or `log_in`? Can you include this method?

Comment: @raidfive Sorry for the update delay, here it is

Comment: So, you are trying to call the `log_in` method in the `UserController` from the `EmployeesController`? This isn't really possible.

Comment: @raidfive Is there any alternative way to do this? Because currently all the methods in my `EmployeeController` need to check if authorized or not. I need to pass this authorization first before I can test my `EmployeeController`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to call a method on the controller in an RSpec controller test, you could use the following.

```
subject.send(:log_in,@user)
```

It should call the method. I dont know if this is really a best practice. A better method would be to stub the logged_in method as BurmajaM suggested.

Comment: what is `subject`? I know I can do `controller.send`, so I'm assuming this is like `User.send(:log_in, @user)`?

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you stub logged_in? or whatever your method is. Logging in is not target of this spec, so stub it! Here's simple example how I spec controller action that has before_filter:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :logged_in?

  def index
  end
end



describe MyController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    context "when not logged in"
      # you want to be sure that before_filter is executed
      it "requires authentication" do
        controller.expects :logged_in?
        get 'index'
      end
      # you don't want to spec that it will redirect you to login_path
      # because that spec belongs to #logged_in? method specs
    end
    context "when authenticated" do
      before(:each) { controller.stubs :logged_in? }
      it "renders :index template" do
        get 'index'
        should render_template(:index)
      end
      it "spec other things your action does when user is logged in"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I did try use stub, but it seems like it doesn't work if I'm in another controller spec file. In this case, I'm in EmployeeController spec and calling UserController

Comment: Hmmm ... that's weird! Why are you calling UserController in EmployeeController spec? It doesn't have to do anything with #logged_in? right?

Comment: `@BurmajaM` There is a authentication check as before_filter for the EmployeeController, which I thought I need to log in to pass this before_filter

Comment: I thought so, that's why I told you to stub it because it is not target of this spec. Before filters are just simple methods that are executed before controller action, thus they can be stubbed like:
    before(:each) { controller.stubs :logged_in? }

Comment: Thanks again, maybe I did something wrong, I will dig into it